# Ellipsis not working correctly in Safari with line-clamp

Tags: css, safari

I'm using line-clamp to limit the titles in a blog to a maximum of two lines. It works fine in firefox and chrome, but in safari the ellipsis doesn't appear where it should, instead it's at the middle of the sentence.

I'm using bootrap 4, but also happens on another project made using Foundation 6, seems to happen when flex is used for the grid.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1 class="title">
            <a href="#">Long title goes here</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the scss

```
$enh1-font-size: 50px;
$enh1-line-height: 60px;
$enh1-lines-to-show: 2;
.title {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-height: $enh1-line-height*$enh1-lines-to-show;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: $enh1-font-size;
  line-height: $enh1-line-height;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $enh1-lines-to-show;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The result should look something like this:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur

adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus dapibus...*

Instead I get this:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur

adipiscing el... Etiam luctus dapibus*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning line clamp css to `h1` assign to **element that has long text** in this case it is `<a href="#">Long title goes here</a>`.